# FlyWay NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, flyway

When migrating using BaseJavaMigration

You need to parse the json string and get the value
For this I use GSON

```
  private String getArtifactVersion(InputStream inputStream) {
    String jsonTemplate = "";
    try {
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      jsonTemplate = writer.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.error("Error read file " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    String artifactVersion = "";
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonTemplate).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Parameters");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
      JsonObject arrObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
      log.info(arrObject.getAsString());
      //      if (arrObject.get.equals("ArtifactVersion")) {
      //        artifactVersion = arrObject.getString("Default");
      //        break;
      //      }
    }
    log.info(artifactVersion);
    return artifactVersion;
  }
```

But when I try to run the **gradle flywayMigrate** command, I get an error

*Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonParser*

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here.
[FlyWay issues](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2355)